# parseInt() and octal - which browsers support it?

Tags: javascript

The javascript parseInt function evaluates '010' as decimal 10, not octal 8, in all of the browsers I've tried - relatively recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE - which is what you'd expect since this has been deprecated for a long time.

But I've got some code that isn't specifying the radix and I'm wondering if someone running an old browser could find a bug. Has anyone compiled a list of which browsers/versions will parse octal? How common is it?

Comment: The latest Chrome, Opera, Safari, and FF give me `8` for `console.log(parseInt(010))`

Comment: `parseInt(010) === 8` and `parseInt('010') === 10` for me in Chrome 40.0.2214.111. According to [MDN's `parseInt` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), treating a leading `0` (in a string) as an implicit radix `8` was allowed, if discouraged, before ECMAScript 5. It is no longer allowed in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: You're not parsing a string - it still recognizes the number 010 as 8 octal but not the string '010'.

Comment: From the MDN page linked above "Many implementations have not adopted this behavior as of 2013, and because older browsers must be supported, **always specify a radix**." (Their emphasis, not mine).  Personally, I'll still be specifying them for the next few years...

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786135

Comment: Note that in code with "use strict" an error will be thrown if an octal number (leading 0) is used in an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 5 forbids parsing such (unspecified radix) strings as octal.  This means IE9 and above will not have a problem (nor will most other browsers - as shown [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#parseInt()_ignores_leading_zeros))

I'd worry about IE8 in this case, as it's possibly still converting to octal given the leading zero and no radix.  (This conversion was only discouraged, not forbidden, in ECMAScript 3 - see [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).)

Comment: ...and I have to support IE8. So I guess I've got some radix specifying to do.

Comment: as mentioned in one of the comments...it's a good idea to always specify the radix - at least for the next couple of years...  :)

Comment: I've found some browsers I could test, and it seems your guess was correct - IE8 says '010' == 8, and IE9 says '010' == 10.

Answer (score 4):

[ECMAScript 3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) said

> When radix is 0 or **undefined** and the string's number begins with a
>   **0** digit not followed by an **x** or **X**, then the implementation may, at its discretion, interpret the number either as being octal or
>   as being decimal. Implementations are encouraged to interpret numbers
>   in this case as being decimal.

[ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) says

> If *radix* is **undefined** or 0, it is assumed to be 10 except when
>   the number begins with the character pairs **0x** or **0X**, in which
>   case a radix of 16 is assumed.

Therefore, all ES5 compliant implementations will parse as decimal and not as octal.